# Simple informix select stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, informix

I am trying to write a simple stored procedure that does a select statement but it keeps giving me a syntax error without any other help telling me what the error is

```
create procedure _this_is_it(this CHAR(3), that CHAR(4), other CHAR(3))
foreach select * from table 
where column1 = this and
column2 = that and
column3 = other
end foreach
end procedure;
```

Any reason why I should get a syntax error?

Comment: try changing `foreach` to `for`

Comment: same deal with the syntax error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `foreach` and the `_` as first letter, also add a `;` at the end of the select.

```
create procedure this_is_it(this CHAR(3), that CHAR(4), other CHAR(3))

select * from table 
where column1 = this and
column2 = that and
column3 = other;

end procedure;
```

Comment: Thats the only way I could get it to work with another query I used.
When I delete those Is till get a sql error.  I wish informix would tell you more information

Comment: even if I do a simple create procedure test select * from testing end procedure.. it still gives me errors

Comment: remove the first underscore in the procedure name and try it again.

Comment: @user867621 check my revised answer.

Comment: That did get rid of the sql errors... now it is asking me to put it into a temp table... thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

If you want to perform some processing inside a foreach loop you have to **SELECT INTO** variables.  So your code would become:

```
drop procedure if exists _this_is_it ;
drop table if exists this_table ;
create temp table this_table(column1 CHAR(3), column2 CHAR(4), column3 CHAR(3))
with no log ;
insert into this_table values("A","B","C") ;

create procedure _this_is_it(this CHAR(3), that CHAR(4), other CHAR(3))
returns CHAR(10) AS something

define f_this CHAR(3) ;
define f_that CHAR(4) ;
define f_other CHAR(3) ;

foreach
select * into f_this, f_that, f_other
from this_table
where column1 = this and
column2 = that and
column3 = other

return f_this||f_that||f_other WITH RESUME ;

end foreach
end procedure;

grant execute on _this_is_it to public;
execute procedure _this_is_it("A","B","C") ;

drop procedure if exists _this_is_it ;
drop table if exists this_table ;
```

Syntax for the FOREACH statement is available from IBM at their [Infocenter](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v117/topic/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1331.htm?resultof=%22FOREACH%22%20%22foreach%22%20).